# E is a collection of sets. How to prove a class/collection of all sets that can be covered by finite union of sets in E is a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory

Given E is any collection of sets $F_i$ ,
Let E1 be a collection of all sets that can be covered by a finite union of sets in E.
How do we show that E1 is a ring?

Or how can we show that E1 is closed under difference?

(I am currently thinking along the line of single element sets, but not sure how to prove this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is finitely coverable, then any subset of $A$ is finitely coverable, hence since
$$A-B=A\cap B^c\subseteq A$$
it follows that $A-B$ is finitely coverable.